# Changing the zoom out action for a UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, zooming

I'm trying to change the way a UIWebView reacts when the user do a pinch out gesture (when he's doing that, I zoom out and show multiple webView).

I see 2 solutions but I can't make them work :

1. Setting scalesPageToFit to YES, and
   then getting events that are sent by
   the API to change the behavior.
   **Problem: I don't find how to catch those events**
2. Setting
   scalesPageToFit to NO, and adding a
   PinchGestureRecognizer on the parent
   of the UIWebView. **Problem:
   The gesture is not well recognize**
   since there are conflicts with the
   scrolling. If the user starts moving
   the first finger before putting down
   the second finger, the scroll begin
   and the pinchGesture is not
   recognize.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the anwser is just to set the delegate of my UIPinchGestureRecognizer to self and to override

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*) otherRecognizer 
{
  return YES;
}
```

Now the pinch is recognized even if the scroll began in the UIWebView